# Statusbar Background Color Changes to White

Tags: java, android, android-statusbar

I have a Status Bar that changes to a white background color when an activity is displayed. The only thing of note about the second activity with the white Status Bar is that it has a Tab-layout and a fragment.

Nowhere am I explicitly setting the Status Bar background color.

I have checked my color.xml and replaced all white and light colors with dark colors just to test to see if it was pulling a color from there.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

**I have no code to add, as I don't know where to even begin to grab any code snippets to show you.**

I have added to the theme

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/COLOR_BLUE</item>
```

and

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Trying to force a change and that did not work either.

Here you can see the background color is my colorPrimaryDark:

[image]

But when I go to the next activity it is a white background.
The text and icons are still there if you look hard enough.

[image]

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.CallsTable"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_call_table"
        android:parentActivityName="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.HomeActivity"/>
    </activity>


          <activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.MasterActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.CallsTable"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.CallsTable"/>
    </activity>
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/COLOR_TXI_LIGHT_BLUE</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/COLOR_TXI_BLUE</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/COLOR_TXI_LIGHT_ORANGE</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>


        <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <style name="DriverTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
            <item name="android:textSize">9dp</item>
        </style>

    </resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
 <resources>
        <color name="COLOR_LIGHT_GREY">#F2F2F2</color>
        <color name="COLOR_GREY">#636363</color>
        <color name="COLOR_SLATE">#796D5A</color>

        <color name="COLOR_RED">#CC2314</color>
        <color name="COLOR_ORANGE">#EF8626</color>
        <color name="COLOR_YELLOW">#F0E500</color>
        <color name="COLOR_GREEN">#9BB209</color>
        <color name="COLOR_BLUE">#3D6999</color>
        <color name="COLOR_PURPLE">#484256</color>

        <color name="COLOR_LIGHT_RED">#FF6A40</color>
        <color name="COLOR_LIGHT_ORANGE">#FFA200</color>
        <color name="COLOR_LIGHT_YELLOW">#FFF662</color>
        <color name="COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN">#C5D84B</color>
        <color name="COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE">#568dc9</color>
        <color name="COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE">#9782C9</color>

        <color name="COLOR_DEBUG">#6F0000</color>
        <color name="COLOR_WHITE">#ffffff</color>
    </resources>
```

Comment: *I have checked my color.xml and replaced all white and light colors with dark colors just to test to see if it was pulling a color from there* Did that work ? Is the code is all yours or copied content you may also check the style of the perticular activity in manifest

Comment: No, changing the colors light colors to dark did not work. The code is all mine.I will look that the manifest

Comment: @Charuක I checked my manifest and nothing out of the ordinary. I posted a partial manifest and some other files.

Comment: check your activity pls. you may have added a theme programmatically.